# How to enqueue or include json file to a plugin

Tags: plugin-development, wp-enqueue-script, json

I have a file called `settings.html` that includes two files in the footer which are a javascript file and a json file.

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
<script src="settings.json"></script>
```

Basically, my javascript file needs the json file to work properly.

In my `plugin.php` file I enqueued my javascript file as well as my json file like the following.

I know how to enqueue a javascript but not a json file so I tried something like this:

```
function enqueue() {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'json_settings', plugins_url('settings.json', FILE,true) );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'js_script', plugins_url('script.js',array('json_settings') ,FILE),true );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue' );
```

The problem here is that my javascript file works but without the json file. My javascript file cannot reach the data inside the json file.

Comment: You can’t put json in script tags like that. You need to either make an AJAX request to the file or read the contents of the JSON file and use it in wp_add_inline_script().

Comment: I didn't know about wp_add_inline_script().
Is that function add code to a enqueued script?

Can I read the json file like that ?
`$json_data = file_get_contents('jsonFile.json');
$json_data = json_decode($json_data, true);`

Then
`wp_add_inline_script( 'js_script', $json_data,'before');`